# How to determine length of JSON representation before serialization

Tags: c#, json, angularjs

I am doing an angular application for showing production plan for the selected year.
The json data from server is parsed and binded to a model so that angular takes care of changing the view.

I have written the web service in aspx and serialize as

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json = serializer.Serialize(planData);
```

where planData is  a list of class

```
  List<IPlan> planData = (List<IPlan>)HttpContext.Current.Session["PlanData"];
```

The problem is there is a maximum limit to the number of characters that can be serialized.

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647">
</jsonSerialization>
```

The above setting determines the maximum number of characters that can be serialized.

So I plan to perform a lazy loading if the character count is greater than permitted.

How can I find the number of characters in a list of custom class?

Comment: Better title: determine length of JSON representation **before** serialization

Comment: Did you ever count characters in a small planData and estimate how much bigger it can be before hitting 2147483647?

Comment: @DrKoch. No. I don't know how to iterate through list and get number of characters

Comment: please show an example of IPlan, what are typical sizes of its members?

Comment: Will be int32,string represting components of a plan

Answer (score 4):

#### The cheap, simple, but conservative approach:

Do the properties in IPlan have size limits? Typically they would. Construct an example instance of IPlan, with each property set to its largest value. Serialize that and get its length. Now divide maxJsonLength by the length you got, and that's approximately the maximum number of items you can return, in the worst case. If maxJsonLength is actually set to the value you have in your snippet, that allows for 2GB of payload, which seems much higher than you'd ever hit in practice for a list of human-readable entities. Maybe that limit is too high? (That's another discussion).

#### The expensive, dumb approach (not recommended)

```
// opening '[' and closing ']' for JSON array
int serializedSize = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < plans.Length; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        // account for commas that occur between items
        serializedSize++;
    }

    serializedSize += serializer.Serialize(plan).Length;
    if (serializedSize > maxJsonLength)
    {
        // now you know where to stop
    }
}
```

This is expensive because you're effectively doing all of the serialization twice -- once for the calculation and once for the actual response. It's also brittle, as this code would have to change if anything changed in the serialization of the array.

It's best to do the first approach and pick a safe max number of items to return, especially if your limit really is 2 gigs.

Comment: not sure if `.Length` is the right way to go as the string length and the byte size might differ.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of (similar) objects you can Serialize one or a handful of them, calculate the size of the serialized JSON string and estimate the size of the complete list (as JSON) by extrapolation.

Comment: There won't be similar objects as the character values differ for each item in list(plan for each day)

Comment: Why don't always lazyload? Or just always add a smaller number of items and lazyload the rest. The items per day cannot be counted? Load by day, not all at once?

Comment: @Robert_Junior he said similar not "the same" it's basically an application of "the big number rule" take a sample if the sample is representative of the set you can use the average size of the sample as the average size of the set